# VB6 apps installed by NSIS, work on Windows 7 but '...not correctly registered...' on Windows 7 SP1

Tags: windows-7, vb6, nsis, reg-free

I am puzzled, I thought I had my NSIS installation packages tested and working on Windows 7 32Bit and 64Bit.

Today I get failures to run on:
 my Laptop PC (Windows 7 Pro 32Bit SP1)
 VMWare Windows 7 Home Premium 64Bit SP1

Successful running on
 VMWare Windows 7 Home Premium 32Bit 
 Windows XP Pro SP3

The installation goes as expected.
Running the application has the Error Message:
Component '---.ocx' or one of its dependencies not correctly registered: a file is missing or invalid.
At this point the flagged reference files include: MSCOMCT2.OCX, RICHTX32.OCX and threed32.ocx .

The install process places the reference files and manifest files in the install folder.

This 'Everything needed' is achieved by including manifest files (reg-free COM),thus, refraining from use of the PC Registry.
e.g.:
File "C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSVBVM60.dll"
File "D:\Devlpmnt\LANG\VB6_dllManifest\MSVBVM60.dll.manifest"

I thought sure that I had successfully tested the VMWare Windows 7 Home Premium 64Bit SP1 installation, August 2013.

The only difference, I can think of, is that all of the failing Win7 platforms have 'Service Pack 1'.

Could the 'Superfetch' mentioned in:
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vistacompatteam/archive/2006/11/13/manifest-and-the-fusion-cache.aspx
have been added to Windows 7 by SP1 and be causing the problem?  If so, how can I fix that?

Comment: I looked at the comments about the 'Superfetch'.  They were pretty old re: Vista.  Near the end of the comments I found: "SetsunaaaSetsunaaa
Jan 06, 2009 at 1:45 PM
Very interesting, I love to hear guys who know what they talk about.

The only thing that happened to me with superfetch is that it ran havoc a week ago (caching 9 GB game data files before logon, with 4 GB of physical RAM), which could be resetted by deleting C:\Windows\Prefetch\Ag*.db.

Otherwise superfetch works really very well, I can only recommend to leave it on."    I cut and pasted the Ag*.db files elsewhere. DID NOT WORK

Comment: I do need to find a solution to the Error message: '…not correctly registered…'

Comment: I looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489165/vb6-manifest-not-working-on-windows-7?rq=1                A comment, there suggested 'Run As Administrator'.  I tried that.  I could.  'Just plain running' it worked the next time.   A temporary 'get around'.  I need a solution, please!